# Как заставить библиотеку Newtonsoft.Json не конвертировать URL внутри XML

Tags: json, xml, vb.net

Имеется метод конвертации JSON в XML

```
Function ToXML(ByVal json As String) As String

    Dim node As XNode = JsonConvert.DeserializeXNode(json, "file", True)

    Return node.ToString()

End Function
```

Во входном JSON присутствуют подобные строки.

```
/index.php?option=com_advs&task=lev_2&region=$1&city=$2&page=$2
```

После конвертации внутри XML они становятся такими

```
/index.php?option=com_advs&amp;task=lev_1&amp;region=$1&amp;page=$2
```

Как это исправить?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Это - корректное поведение, ведь `&` - спецсимвол. Любой XML-парсер при чтении конвертирует вам ваши URL обратно.

---

Небольшое разъяснение. Надо отделять мухи от котлет: непосредственно заменой `&` на `&amp;` библиотека Newtonsoft.Json не занимается! И даже классы Linq2Xml этого сами не делают. Экранированием спецсимволов занимается класс [`XmlWriter`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.xml.xmlwriter(v=vs.110).aspx) и его наследники, однако напрямую настроить его чтобы он не экранировал спецсимволы не получится.

Comment: Парсер возможно и любой, а вот XSLT трансформатор например встроенный в NET, не конвертирует обратно..

Comment: @ДмитрийГвоздь еще как конвертирует. Надо только правильный выходной формат поставить. Я вам, кстати, уже писал про него.